# Gitlab templates with pluses in name

Tags: gitlab

In my Gitlab instance ([gitlab/gitlab-ce](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/):11.4.5-ce.0) I cannot access these C++ two templates (not through the API and not via the webpage):

- /api/v4/projects/1/templates/gitignores/C++
- /api/v4/projects/1/templates/gitlab_ci_ymls/C++

This is probably due to the plus characters in their names. How can I debug the problem further / how can I fix this?

Comment: It might be something to do with [HTML encoding](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html#namespaced-path-encoding), maybe try using `%2B%2B` instead of `++`?

Comment: @Rekovni: thank you for the suggestion, I am expecting it is something like that. But first of all, using %2B%2B in the API URLs does not help and second of all a hack of the URL would not help with trying to use a template from within the webpage editor.

Answer (score 1):

this is an open issue upstream: 
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/52942

Comment: Thank you for finding this bug report. And that does mention one "fix" / workaround (renaming the offending template-files). But I was also asking for tips on further debugging and when asking for a "fix" I hoped for something more than renaming the template-files. So I will not mark this as a solution (yet).